# List Comprehension to Create Vector Twice the Square of a Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, indexing, list-comprehension

I need to write a list comprehension to create a vector twice the square of the middle column of a matrix. (My matrix `x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`.) Problem is, I know how to extract the middle column BUT I don't know how to square it or double the square. Any help would be greatly appreciated (...still learning but trying my best)!

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
print(x)

z = [b[1] for b in x]
print(z)
```

Comment: Try `z = [b[1]**2 for b in x]` or `z = [b[1]*2 for b in x]` for square and double, respectively

Comment: Chris, thank youuu! That took me hours to try to decipher. Your answer was very helpful! :)

Comment: BTW, it is very inefficient way of doing math operation since you are already using `numpy`. Unless the purpose is purely toying around with list comprehension, try making the best use out of `numpy`'s broadcasting ability.

Answer (score 0):

To create a vector twice the square of the column:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
print(x)
```

### with a list comprehension: (not recommended)

```
z = [2*b[1]**2 for b in x]
print(z)
```

The output is a **python list**:

```
[8, 50, 128]
```

### using numpy indexing: (recommended)

more info [here](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Indexing.html)

```
z = 2 * x[:,1] ** 2 
print(z)
```

The output is a **numpy array**:

```
[  8  50 128]
```